# Relationships between half-iterates of trig functions

Tags: trigonometry, function-and-relation-composition

Let the function $\operatorname{hsin}(x)$ be defined as a continuous function with the property
$$\operatorname{hsin}(\operatorname{hsin}(x))=\sin x$$
and let other half-trig functions be defined analogously, so that
$$\operatorname{hcos}(\operatorname{hcos}(x))=\cos x$$
$$\operatorname{htan}(\operatorname{htan}(x))=\tan x$$
$$\operatorname{hsec}(\operatorname{hsec}(x))=\sec x$$
$$\operatorname{hcsc}(\operatorname{hcsc}(x))=\csc x$$
$$\operatorname{hcot}(\operatorname{hcot}(x))=\cot x$$
There are a vast multitude of identities involving trig functions, like
$$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$$
and
$$\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$$
to name just a few. Can anybody find any interesting identities that can be determined about the half-trig functions, without just taking normal trig identities and substituting in the definitions?

For example, can we find a way to express $\operatorname{htan}(x)$ in terms of $\operatorname{hsin}(x)$ and $\operatorname{hcos}(x)$? Or, in other words, can we find a function $f$ such that
$$\operatorname{htan}(x)=f(\operatorname{hsin}(x),\operatorname{hcos}(x))$$

Comment: The first couple of terms in the power series for $ \operatorname{hsin}(x)$ are
\begin{eqnarray*} 
\operatorname{hsin}(x)= x - \frac{1}{12}x^3-\frac{1}{160}x^5 + \cdots
\end{eqnarray*}
$- \frac{1}{12}$ reminds me of something $ \ddot \smile$

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit 's expansion may be found here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45608/does-the-formal-power-series-solution-to-ffx-sin-x-converge

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thank you for the link ... there is some interesting stuff there.

Answer (score 0):

For invertible functions without constant term one can use a "q&d"-method to compute/approximate the half-iteratives: the adaption of the iterative Newton-method to find square-roots.

In Pari/GP this is especially convenient, because you can work with formal powerseries as variables and their inversion.

The following method approximates the powerseries for the halfiterative of the $\sin()$-function

```
\ps 32  \\ define default order for powerseries

\\ initialization
hsin = x + O(x^32)     \\ assume hsin being initially a simple powerseries

\\ iteration
hsin = (sin(serreverse(hsin)) + hsin )/2)  \\ iterate this Newton-adaption 
                                           \\ until convergence

\\ show the formal powerseries for the half-iterate
hsin
   x - 1/12*x^3 - 1/160*x^5 - 53/40320*x^7 - 23/71680*x^9 - ... + O(x^32)
```

---

I implemented this in the following way and show a small example-value $x_0=0.2$
***hsin()***

```
hsin = x + O(x^32)
for(k=1,20,hsin =(sin(serreverse(hsin )) + hsin )/2) \\20 iterations suffice
                                      \\ for "\ps 32"  and 12 visible digits

x0 = 0.2
x05=subst(Pol(hsin ),x, x0)   \\ inserting the x0 in the powerseries hsin
x1 =subst(Pol(hsin ),x,x05)
[x0,x05,x1;x0,x0,sin(x0)]
\\ output
\\  x0              x05           x1
[0.200000000000 0.199331316342 0.198669330795]  by hsin(x0)
[0.200000000000 -------------- 0.198669330795]  by sin(x0)
```

Similarly with the $\tan()$-function:
***htan()***

```
htan=x+ O(x^32)
for(k=1,20,htan=(tan(serreverse(htan))+htan)/2)

x0=0.2
x05=subst(Pol(htan),x,x0)
x1=subst(Pol(htan),x,x05)
[x0,x05,x1;x0,x0,tan(x0)]
\\ output  
\\  x0              x05           x1
[0.200000000000 0.201341376827 0.202710035509] by htan(x0)
[0.200000000000 -------------- 0.202710035509] by tan(x0)
```

***hcos()***: Unfortunately, the $\cos()$-function has a constant term and is thus not simply invertible. The assumption, that `hsin(x)/htan(x) = hcos(x)` however, can be checked (and fails!), so this is ***not*** a way to compute the half-iterate for the $\cos()$:

```
x0=0.2
x05=subst(Pol(hsin/htan),x,x0)
x1 =subst(Pol(hsin/htan),x,x05)
[x0,x05,x1;x0,x0,cos(x0)]
\\ output  
\\  x0              x05           x1
[0.200000000000 0.990016654715 0.764529818658]  by hsin(x0)/htan(x0)
[0.200000000000 -------------- 0.980066577841]  by cos(x0)
```

Didn't check the other possible functions.

---

***Important remarks:*** Note that the powerseries of the half-iterates have terms whose absolute value diverges strongly, so strictly spoken we could not evaluate the powerseries for the half-iterates. But the divergence of the coefficients begins only after a handful of leading terms, so using a powerseries "precision" `\ps 32` should not be extended much or might even better be slightly reduced to get more accurate approximations. (We have so called "asymptotic series" which when appropriately truncated give more-or-less rough estimates to some dozen decimal digits)